# Scaning a string input keeps failing

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to get an input string by using `scanf()` in a function, but it keeps failing and I don't know why.

Here is part of my code.

```
typedef struct node {           
    int id;
    char * name;
    char * address;
    char * group;      
    struct node * next;
} data;

void showG(data * head) {   
    char * n = "";
    int i = 0;
    data * current = head;
    scanf("%s", n);
    printf("The group of %s is\n", n);

    while (current != NULL) {
        if (0 == strcmp(current->group, n)) {
            printf("%d,%s,%s\n", current->id, current->name, current->address);
            i = 1;
        }

        current = current->next;
    }
    if (0 == i) {
        printf("no group found");
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, it's..  if i change n to "1" and delete the sentence of scanf, the other part will work, which mean it will printf "The group of 1 is ....." stuff,But if i keep the scanf and run the program, it will stop when i want to type in to change the value of n

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code,

```
char * n = "";
```

makes `n` point to a *string literal* which is usually placed in *read-only* memory area, so cannot be modified. Hence, `n` cannot be used to *scan* another input. What you want, is either of below

- a `char` array, like

  ```
  char n[128] = {0};
  ```
- a pointer to `char` with proper memory allocation.

  ```
   char * n = malloc(128);
  ```

  Please note, if you use [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc), after the usage of `n` is over, you need to [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) the memory, too , to avoid memory leak.

Note: after fixing the above issue,change

```
scanf("%s", n);
```

to

```
scanf("%127s", n);
```

if the allocation is for `128` bytes, to avoid the memory overrun.

Comment: i want the second one

Comment: @JosephYANG then take the second one. :-)

Comment: just try both of  them and decide to take the first one, thanks to both of you